# How to Download latest file in Azure storage using azcopy to a local system

Tags: azure, cmd, blob, azcopy, sas-token

I am new to azure storage. In the azure storage i have a container and i have multiple directory  and i have sub directory inside the container.

Sub directory contains multiple files. I need to download the latest file from the sub directory.

As of now i use the command

```
azcopy cp "https://storageforecast.blob.core.windows.net/test/pollo/pollo1/pollo2/?si=plus&sv=2019-12-12&srMAVZhkpCwrXs1" "E:\111" --recursive

test- container
pollo -directory
pollo1 - subdirectory1
pollo2 - subdirectory2
```

I have multiple files inside pollo2. I need to download the latest file...and how can i do that..Can someone pls help me

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't explicitly looking for a cmd solution, then you can download and install Azure Storage Explorer and connect to your storage accounts. This explorer gives your the options to order by Last Modified Date. You can simply right-click and download the blobs in your containers after ordering by Last Modified Date.
Link to download Azure Storage Explorer : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/

Comment: I need to download the latest files from the cmd line through azcopy...I am looking for the cmd line solution...Could u pls help me for that

Comment: If your container has more than 5000 blobs then the most recent won't necessarily always be loaded. You'll need to click 'load more' until the cache has loaded a list of all blobs in yolur container